# How do i remove session data when browser goes to another website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a `Session` object `Session['cart']` and i need to remove this `Session` data when browser goes to another website. At the moment when i go to another website and come back to the app by typing in the app `URL` on address bar that `Session` value still exists.

How do i remove this?

Comment: You should look into "session timeouts" and perhaps adjusting these to match your requirements.

Comment: @DeanTaylor this session is of Anonymous user of a eCommerce app when i set timeouts its affects all including Authenticated ones

Comment: Try increasing your timeouts for Authenticated users in that case.